# How do I fix error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSExpression.ExpressionType' and '_'

Tags: ios, swift, constants, nsexpression, swift-keypath

I am going through old code from [HomeKit Catalog: Creating Homes, Pairing and Controlling Accessories, and Setting Up Triggers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/HomeKitCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015048) when I ran into an expression that says

```
.KeyPathExpressionType
```

I can't tell what the

```
.
```

in

```
.KeyPathExpressionType
```

is referring to on the left side of the

```
.
```

I find nothing when I search Google and stack**overflow** for "KeyPathExpressionType". It's the same with

```
.ConstantValueExpressionType
```

I find nothing.

Each of those equality comparisons

```
comparison.leftExpression.expressionType == .KeyPathExpressionType
```

and

```
comparison.rightExpression.expressionType == .ConstantValueExpressionType
```

in the code below, generate an error message that says:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSExpression.ExpressionType' and '_'

```
extension NSPredicate {

    /**
        Parses the predicate and attempts to generate a characteristic-value `HomeKitConditionType`.

        - returns:  An optional characteristic-value tuple.
    */
    private func characteristic() -> HomeKitConditionType? {
        guard let predicate = self as? NSCompoundPredicate else { return nil }
        guard let subpredicates = predicate.subpredicates as? [NSPredicate] else { return nil }
        guard subpredicates.count == 2 else { return nil }

        var characteristicPredicate: NSComparisonPredicate? = nil
        var valuePredicate: NSComparisonPredicate? = nil

        for subpredicate in subpredicates {
            if let comparison = subpredicate as? NSComparisonPredicate, comparison.leftExpression.expressionType == .KeyPathExpressionType && comparison.rightExpression.expressionType == .ConstantValueExpressionType {
                switch comparison.leftExpression.keyPath {
                    case HMCharacteristicKeyPath:
                        characteristicPredicate = comparison

                    case HMCharacteristicValueKeyPath:
                        valuePredicate = comparison

                    default:
                        break
                }
            }
        }

        if let characteristic = characteristicPredicate?.rightExpression.constantValue as? HMCharacteristic,
            characteristicValue = valuePredicate?.rightExpression.constantValue as? NSCopying {
                return .Characteristic(characteristic, characteristicValue)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I get the error to go away when I replace

```
comparison.leftExpression.expressionType == .KeyPathExpressionType
```

with

```
comparison.leftExpression.expressionType.rawValue == NSExpression.ExpressionType.keyPath.rawValue
```

and

```
comparison.rightExpression.expressionType == .ConstantValueExpressionType
```

with

```
comparison.rightExpression.expressionType.rawValue == NSExpression.ExpressionType.constantValue.rawValue
```

Is this correct? Can anyone tell me enlighten me on this problem?

Comment: Not sure, but it seems like `.KeyPathExpressionType` is the old name of `.keyPath`. Can you try `comparison.leftExpression.expressionType == .keyPath` ?

Comment: Yes. That works. I actually typed "NSExpression.ExpressionType.keyPath".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is outdated Swift 2 code.

Replace `.KeyPathExpressionType` with `.keyPath` and `.ConstantValueExpressionType` with `.constantValue`

The type is `NSExpression.ExpressionType`, please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1416975-expressiontype)

Comment: I used "NSExpression.ExpressionType.keyPath" and "NSExpression.ExpressionType.constantValue" and it works. Thank you.

Comment: You can omit `NSExpression.ExpressionType`, the compiler infers the type.